# How to modify selenium webdriver dns to custom one

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dns, webdriver

so for some reason my webdriver session does not able to enter some website that on my normal browser I can, I receive DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error.

I tried manually change the DNS provider to CloudFlare (1.1.1.1)

[image]

and then it worked, how can I make the webdriver be loaded with that settings?

I tried the following code snipper

```
chrome_options = options.Options()
local_state = {
    "dns_over_https.mode": "automatic",
    "dns_over_https.templates": "1.1.1.1",
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('localState', local_state)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
```

And few more variations, can't find anything on google nor here.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it work with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


local_state = {
    "dns_over_https.mode": "secure",
#   "dns_over_https.templates": "https://dns.google/dns-query{?dns}",
    "dns_over_https.templates": "https://chrome.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query",
}
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('localState', local_state)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('chrome://settings/security')
driver.get('https://1.1.1.1/help')

input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

`dns_over_https.templates` is not well [documented](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::DnsOverHttpsTemplates).

Please take a look at the [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/3bf883a7f40dc6be73841af8cff2446f8fedeac0:net/dns/public/doh_provider_entry.cc;l=68-308).